# Ghostscript.NET and trouble with converted file dimensions

Tags: c#, file, bitmap, ghostscript, eps

I'm trying to handle the **Ghostscript.NET 1.2.0.0** plugin to convert an .eps file to .bmp using a program written in C# with Windows Forms.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ghostscript.NET/1.2.0

My results are far from good and I'm not really able to pinpoint the cause of the problem.
Here is the part of my code:

```
void ButtonConvertClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputFilePath = @"C:\Users\Karlsson\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Converter\Converter\bin\calibration.eps";
        string outputFilePath = @"C:\Users\Karlsson\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Converter\Converter\bin\calibration_csharp.bmp";

        using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
            {
    
                rasterizer.Open(inputFilePath);

                var image = rasterizer.GetPage(72,72,0);

                var bmp = new Bitmap(image);

                bmp.Save(outputFilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

                pictureBox.Image = bmp;

                rasterizer.Close();
                
            }
           
    }
```

The test file was the calibration.txt file, which was an image recording from the Tektronix oscilloscope.

[calibration.txt](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/connecting-tds210-to-computer-via-rs323-serial-to-usb/?action=dlattach;attach=809271)

**To make the conversion possible, I changed the extension of this file from .txt to .eps.**

Before I talk about the result of the conversion done by my C# code, I'll show how it is made by convert.io online converter https://convertio.co/eps-bmp/

[image: calibration]

(**Here I manually changed the photo to .jpg to save on size**)

The .eps converted with my C# code looks **completely different** - the actual horizontal image takes up a small area of ​​a vertically oriented white sheet.

[image: calibration_csharp]

(**Here I also changed manually the photo to .jpg to save on size**)

*rasterizer.GetPage* only scales the image, while the proportion of the size of the drawing to the surrounding background is the same. I am not able to adjust the size as in the result image from convert.io. Of course, I realize that this online converter is much more advanced, however, it somehow handles this .eps file.

I decided to check out some other sample .eps files and found this page:

[https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/eps/eps.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/eps/eps.html)

So I took some sample .eps files and here is what I achieved with one of them (I selected *mathematica.eps, a simple graph*):

[image: mathematica.bmp]

**Of course I replaced calibration.eps with mathematica.eps in my code.**

Suddenly, it turned out that my C# code using Ghostscript coped with the image and its resolution and overall size **are identical** to the size of this example placed as a pattern on the page.

It also turns out that the second .eps file is built a bit differently and it probably has some influence on the conversion method. But can you find an explanation as to why my code failed with the Calibration.eps file (adds a white background to the image) while it handled the second image perfectly? I don't know much about PostScript.

Comment: The first thing to appreciate is that EPS files are intended for inclusion in other documents, not for rendering 'stand-alone'. So sizing and placement should be done by the application including the EPS program. Now Ghostscript has some non-standard capabilities which allow it to detect 'naked' EPS files and alter the media size to match the BoundingBox of the EPS. Your EPS file claims compliance with a very old version of DSC, and hence EPS. It's claiming DSC 2.0 and EPSF 1.2, current version of each is 3.0 (since 1992)

Comment: It looks to me like that is simply defeating the auto-detection, so your EPS is rendered on the default media, which will be A4 or Letter. If you specify -dEPSCrop which prompt GS to look for and use the %BoundingBox comment, then it will render just the BoundingBox. Alternatively you would need to set the media size and translate the EPS to the correct location yourself, as an application using an EPS file would do. Of course all this is based on Ghostscript, not Ghostscript.NET.

Comment: FWIW mathematica.eps **also** renders to a default page for me, the difference being that it has it's origin at 0,0 (bottom left) which your calibration file does not. -dEPSCrop works for both these files.

Comment: @KenS, I can confirm this is a bug in Ghostscript.NET. When Ghostscript.NET reads "%%BoundingBox" values, it expects line to end with either \n or \r\n. In this case it looks like the file in question was generated on MAC so the line ends with \r. I have fixed that locally and now I get result as expected.

Comment: ...............Apple :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Ghostscript.NET library.

This is now patched (https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/Ghostscript.NET/commit/814b25eb50770ee4649600911f4bbb8a5638281c)

The new library has not yet been officially released, but you can obtain the most recent source code and compile it on your own.